# Data when loaded from oracle to greenplum via talend is not handling CLOB columns well

Tags: oracle, talend, greenplum

I am using *tOracleConnection* to connect to the oracle source and *tOracleInput* to fetch the data, then *tMap* and then writing the data to a file using *tfileoutputdelimited* (custom component)

From file I am loading the data into Greenplum using *tGreenPlumLoad*.

All the data is getting loaded fine execpt for one column which has CLOB data.
data which needs to get loaded as

```
(CLOB)2*C111*SUB_TYPE_CD2*N118*Tool Investigation2*O10
```

but the data in the column says

```
oracle.sql.CLOB@6513543e
```

For few records this issue is happening, for other records CLOB data is getting loaded fine.

I want CLOB data to get loaded into the columns for all records.

Comment: I've seen this happening when I used dynamic type, for that I had to modify the code that comes with talend. I've raised a request with them for the same. Which Talend version are you using?

Comment: @BalazsGunics I am using Talend studio enterprise version 5.6.1.

Answer (score 1):

Talend 5.6.1 has many bugs, this is one of them. When I tried to use Dynamic type I faced this issue as well.

Locate this file:

```
Talend-5.6.1\plugins\org.talend.desinger.routines.tisprovider_5.6.1.20141207_1530\resources\java\routines\system\DynamicUtils.java
```

The modify the following routine like this:

```
    public static void readColumnsFromDatabase(Dynamic column, java.sql.ResultSet rs, int fixedColumnCount) throws Exception {
    column.clearColumnValues();
    for (int i = 0; i < column.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        DynamicMetadata dcm = column.getColumnMetadata(i);
        if ("id_String".equals(dcm.getType()) && !"BLOB".equals(dcm.getDbType()) ) {
            column.addColumnValue(rs.getString(fixedColumnCount + i + 1));
        } else if ("id_Date".equals(dcm.getType())) {
            if (DBMSConstants.MSSQL.getDBmsId().equalsIgnoreCase(column.getDbmsId())
                    && !(dcm.getDbType().toLowerCase().indexOf("timestamp") < 0)) {
                column.addColumnValue(rs.getString(fixedColumnCount + i + 1));
            } else if (DBMSConstants.NETEZZA.getDBmsId().equalsIgnoreCase(column.getDbmsId())
                    && "time".equalsIgnoreCase(dcm.getDbType())) {
                column.addColumnValue(rs.getTime(fixedColumnCount + i + 1));
            } else {
                column.addColumnValue(rs.getTimestamp(fixedColumnCount + i + 1));
            }
        } else if ("id_Integer".equals(dcm.getType()) || "id_Long".equals(dcm.getType()) || "id_Double".equals(dcm.getType())
                || "id_Byte".equals(dcm.getType()) || "id_byte[]".equals(dcm.getType()) || "BLOB".equals(dcm.getDbType())
                || "CLOB".equals(dcm.getDbType()) ) {

            //oracle ...
            if ( "LONG RAW".equals(dcm.getDbType()) ) {
                java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                java.io.InputStream in = rs.getBinaryStream(fixedColumnCount + i + 1);
                if (in == null) {
                    column.addColumnValue(null);
                    continue;
                }
                int n = 0;
                while ((n=in.read(buf))>=0)
                {
                   baos.write(buf, 0, n);
                }
                in.close();
                column.addColumnValue(baos.toByteArray());
                continue;
            }

            if (rs.getObject(fixedColumnCount + i + 1) == null) {
                column.addColumnValue(null);
                continue;
            }
            if ("id_Integer".equals(dcm.getType())) {
                column.addColumnValue(rs.getInt(fixedColumnCount + i + 1));
            } else if ("id_Long".equals(dcm.getType())) {
                column.addColumnValue(rs.getLong(fixedColumnCount + i + 1));
            } else if ("id_Double".equals(dcm.getType())) {
                column.addColumnValue(rs.getDouble(fixedColumnCount + i + 1));
            } else if ("id_Byte".equals(dcm.getType())) {
                column.addColumnValue(rs.getByte(fixedColumnCount + i + 1));
            } else if ("id_byte[]".equals(dcm.getType())) {
                       column.addColumnValue(rs.getBytes(fixedColumnCount + i + 1));
                    } else if ( "BLOB".equals(dcm.getDbType()) ) {
               column.addColumnValue(rs.getBytes(fixedColumnCount + i + 1));
            } else if ( "CLOB".equals(dcm.getDbType()) ) {
               column.addColumnValue(rs.getString(fixedColumnCount + i + 1));
            }
        } else {
            column.addColumnValue(rs.getObject(fixedColumnCount + i + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

This contains a fix for oracle long raw type as well. I'm not entirely sure what needs to be done if you're NOT using dynamic types, but based on this you should check how talend extracts the data from that column.

It should use: `rs.getString(n)` and not `rs.getObject(n)`

Ask your Talend representitive as they have a patch for this behaviour since a year or so.

Comment: Hi, how would i know what procedure my job is using ? Is there a way to find out how talend extracts the data from column?

Comment: Can you post the link here where u had reported this bug to the talend team?

Comment: I am planning to add a java routine and call in tmap. But is it possible to tweak the code u have mentioned in talend?

Comment: I don't follow you, I provided you the location of the routine and how to modify it. What else could I do? :)

Comment: Case Number 00009467
Oracle CLOB is not mapped to id_String

You have to modify the input components schema, and map CLOB to java String.